# Why does this hash syntax not work in Rails?

Tags: hash, ruby-on-rails-3

```
session[:user => user, :user_id => [user.id, user.salt]]
```

For some reason, that never worked for me.

Thoughts on how I can achieve the following code in one line:

```
session[:user] = user
session[:user_id] = [user.id, user.salt]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stuck with the original syntax, because I couldn't find an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 session.merge({:user => user, :user_id => [user.id, user.salt]})
```